Confused by two different answer: supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$
So I was going to check if I could be right in this: $\sqrt{2} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$ hence if a function, in $\mathbb{R}$ has a maximum at that point, studying it over $\mathbb{Q}$ wouldn't lead to the same result since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
So I thought that in $\mathbb{Q}$ that point would be "useless" and the function has no max.
The question then did arise in my mind: does the function have a sup at that point? And My answer was a big no because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational and I cannot think of the closest number to $\sqrt{2}$.
Yet over here I found those:
proving existence of supremum in $\mathbb Q$
How to prove the set $\left\{ q\in\mathbb{Q}\ |\ q^{2}\le2\right\}$ has no supermum in $\mathbb{Q}$ without Real numbers?
Which they state a different answer: one says the sup exists, the other that doesn't.
How would I consider the point $\sqrt{2}$ for a function $f(x)$ when studying it in $\mathbb{Q}$, if in $\mathbb{R}$ that is a max?

The first question seems to be talking about the set ${x : x \in \mathbb Q, x^3 < 2}$ viewed as a subset of $\mathbb R$.

@MishaLavrov Ah, so if I see $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$ there is a sup, while when $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ there is not. This makes sense, I didn't understand they worked in that way in the first question... Thanks!

Note the two linked questions don't contradict.  The former is talking about the supremum existing as a real number.  The latter is saying it isn't rational.

@BrianMoehring Ok! I think I got it. So if I have a function that has a max in $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, what can I say in $\mathbb{Q}$? Does that becomes a sup or nothing?

It would depend on context.  Usually, we'd pass up to $\mathbb{R}$, make the conclusion there, and pass back down.  Sometimes we cannot do this.  If you have a concrete example, more might be said.

@BrianMoehring I have the function $(2x+x^2)e^{-x}$. It has a max at $\sqrt{2}$ and a min at $-\sqrt{2}$, studying it in $[-4, 4] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. But then I'm asked to study it over $\mathbb{Q}$

On either $[-4,4] \subseteq R$ or $\mathbb Q \cap [-4,4]$, $(2x+x^2) e^{-x}$ has a maximum value at $x = -4$.  At $\sqrt{2}$ it just has a local max.

@RobertIsrael How can $\sqrt{2}$ be treated as a local max if $\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$?

@RobertIsrael Notice that I'm solving the problem in $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subset of itself, not as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$...

$\sqrt{2}$ is not a local max in $\mathbb Q$.  My point was that it isn't the maximum on $[-4,4]$ either.

@RobertIsrael Ok, but what if instead we had $\mathbb{Q} \cap [-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$? In that case I would have no max, because $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational. Also I wouldn't manage to reach the closest value to $\sqrt{2}$, hence no max at all

Yes, on $\mathbb Q \cap [-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$ your function has no maximum.  I don't know what you mean by "the closest value to $\sqrt{2}$".  There are rational numbers arbitrarily close to $\sqrt{2}$, so there is no "closest".
